# How do i assign TextFields value (i.e text) to UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, ios8

What i want to do is that if i write something in TextField then it must get displayed in TableView

Comment: Why Is Every Word Capitalised In The Question?

Comment: because he/she thought it is facebook chat or something like that. Where fancy things are welcomed.

Comment: @user3693546: The User Is A *HE* Boy.

Comment: reload your table view ever time when u write something in text view and after that in cell for row methos of tableview write this code.   cell.titleLabel.text=txtview.text;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is straight forward.

Implement delegates/datasource methods for UITableView.

Make an array to hold user input(s). This array will be used as datasource to populate the table.

Reload the tableView.

Answer (score 0):

I always use searchBar in tableView, Implement searchBar's delegate ,then set  cell's text changed when you input searchString.